# how can i give padding to images which are inside linearlayout without increasing linearlayout width in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing this layout in my android xml file

[image]

I am putting 2 linear layout 1 for the header and other for the body. so far all good. In the header liner layout i added the background image which comes perfectly fine.

Now when i am adding the right most image button for search and information, i want them to float through the header linear layout exactly as shown above. But the problem is if i put them into header linerlayout the width of the liner layout increases and both of them comes under the header layout. Is there anyway i can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this combination:

```
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget68"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="40px"
        android:layout_y="35px"
        >        
        <ImageView
            android:src = "@drawable/androidlogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />            
        <Button
            android:layout_width="124px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Print Picture"       
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

to get this:

[image: Frame layout]

You may also move your picture (button in this case) by padding it